# Getting @FormDataParam from an Injectable Context

Tags: rest, jersey

Is there a way to get `@FormDataParam` or even `@FormParam` from an **Injectable Context**? Equivalent to `@Context UriInfo`, or `@Context Request` where we can get *querys* and *pathparams* from from these **injectables**.

I couldn't find anything to retrieve the data POST using `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` or even `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

When I run `curl -X POST --data "description=test" http://localhost:8084/mytest/ws` the WS method accepts the request, however, I couldn't find the data passed in any @Context injectable. I would like to know if it's even possible.

If not, what is the best way? Should I really use `@FormDataParam` as parameters in the interceptor method?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Do you mean you want to inject some `@Context` into the method parameter, and get the form data from that? What is the purpose? What's wrong with the `@FormDataParam` and `@FormParam`?

Comment: @peeskillet, in fact I wouldn't inject some `@Context` into the method parameter, but in the class attribute itself. That's why. I'm trying to make an abstract resource as generic as possible. Using `@FormDataParam` I would have to specify when is multipart or urlencoded or queryparam or simple pathparam. If I could inject some `@Context` in the class attribute, I wouldn't need specify what tipe of data it would receive.

Comment: You can get everything from the `ContainerRequest` (which can be injected). If you want a specific type of entity, you can `cr.readEntity(...)`. For urlencoded, you can `readEntity(Form.class)`. For form-data you can use [`FormDataMultiPart`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataMultiPart.html)

Comment: It's working for while. The ContainerRequest class is interesting. Thank you @peeskillet